# Como utilizar a instrução merge em sql server

Tags: sql-server

Gostaria de saber como utilizar a instrução **MERGE**. Quando devo utilizar e quais as vantagens e desvantagens de usar?

Answer (score 2):

Por definição o comando [MERGE](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql):

> Realiza operações de inserção, atualização ou exclusão em uma tabela
>   de destino com base nos resultados da junção com a tabela de origem.
>   Por exemplo, você pode sincronizar duas tabelas inserindo, atualizando
>   ou excluindo linhas em uma tabela com base nas diferenças encontradas
>   na outra tabela.

**Resumo:**

De forma mas simplificada com `merge` você consegue configurar comparações entre duas fontes de dados(Origem e destino) e definir instruções(insert, update, delete) para executar de acordo com o resultado da comparação.

**Como funciona:**

`MERGE` => Define o destino que receberá os dados processados, este destino pode ser entendido como uma Tabela ou uma View. Todas as alterações ocorrerão neste destino independentemente de qual seja a alteração ou a origem dos dados.

`USING` => Especifica a origem dos dados e baseado nas condições da clausula `ON`, Verifica a relação dos dados de origem com o destino. Esta origem pode ser determinada por uma Tabela, uma View ou até uma Function. Ela será utilizada como base para alterar o destino e não sofrerá nenhuma alteração em seus dados.

`ON` => Especifica a condição de comparação das tabelas e segue o mesmo conceito do `ON` utilizado em um `JOIN`.

`WHEN MATCHED` ou `WHEN NOT MATCHED` => Determina qual ação será realizada no destino, no final da instrução sempre vem acompanhado do termo `THEN`. 
Nesta cláusula, é possível inserir filtros como fazemos em um `WHERE`, com o objetivo de restringir as possibilidades e deixar o funcionamento mais exato e granular possível. Pode-se utilizar `ANDs` ou `ORs` em quantas ocorrências de `WHEN` forem necessárias.

**Exemplo:**

```
MERGE db1.Usuario AS Destino

USING db2.Usuario AS Origem -- A origem pode ser uma tabela, uma consulta..

ON Destino.CPF = Origem.CPF

-- Quando houver registros em ambas com mesmo CPF e a data de alteração da 
-- origem for maior que a data de alteração da destino fará um update..
WHEN MATCHED AND Origem.DataAlteracao > Destino.DataAlteracao THEN 
THEN 
  UPDATE SET Senha = Origem.Senha
  , DataAlteracao = Origem.DataAlteracao

-- Quando não houver registros em ambas com mesmo CPF
-- Inserirá o registro no Destino
WHEN NOT MATCHED
THEN 
    INSERT (CPF, Login, Senha, DataAlteracao) 
    VALUES (Origem.CPF, Origem.Login, Origem.Senha, Origem.DataAlteracao)
```

No exemplo acima faço a comparação da tabela usuário de um banco com o outro, caso os dados da origem forem alterados(identifico isso através da data de alteração) então atualizo os dados no destino, caso não exista o usuário no destino seguinifica que é um novo usuário e portanto eu crio ele no destino.

**Quando deve usar:**

A palavra dever aqui é um pouco complicada, pois tudo varia de acordo com sua necessidade, seu modelo de negócio, sua base de dados.

Basicamente sempre que você identificar a necessidade de comparar duas fontes de dados para depois manipulá-los então você identificou uma situação em que se **Pode** fazer uso do `merge`.

**Fontes**:

- [Microsoft](https://technet.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx)
- [Devmedia](https://www.devmedia.com.br/artigo-sql-magazine-55-aplicando-merge-com-sql-server-2008/10360)
- [SqlGo](https://sqlgo.wordpress.com/2011/04/23/usando-o-comando-merge/)